# PHP test page is showing blank

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to set up PHP to work with Apache using Apache Module DLL. The following code is added to **c:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf** file:

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/PHP/php5apache2_4.dll
<IfModule php5_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
    PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
</IfModule>
```

Then I browse http://localhost in a browser and it shows a page saying "It Works!"

Then again I test browse a PHP page **info.php** which just calls phpinfo() and it shows quite a bit of info about PHP installation.

Now, the case is that I found two default files such as **php.ini-production** and **php.ini-development** and I copy any one of them and save it as **php.ini** in 
"C:/PHP",restarts the Apache server and again test browse **info.php**,then this time the page is blank even without any error message.

What might be the issue and how should I try to solve it?

My software specification is outlined below:

OS:  **Windows 7**

PHP: **5.6.29**

Apache: **2.4.23-win32-VC14**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could compare the INI files. Then you'll see what setting(s) lead(s) to this behaviour. Then you can look up those setting in the manual to find out what they do. If I had to guess (which I do, because you didn't actually show us your code), you wrote `<? phpinfo() ?>` and have short-tags off in those configurations. View source in your browser and you'll see that its been sent to your browser verbatim.

Comment: Check the web server error log. You may find the error details there.